# Trying to get a random code which can be checked against the output

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to have a while loop which asks the user to enter the shuffled code

- If true then `login_success()` runs
- Else `twofactor()` runs

However, I can't get to match the input to the shuffled code, is this to do with it being a list? I've tried `.map` and `.join` but no luck.

```
def twofactor():

    global RandomCode
    RandomCode = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    flag = True

    while flag:
        random.shuffle(RandomCode)
        print(str(RandomCode[0:6]))
        entercode = str(input("Enter the code: "))
        if entercode != RandomCode:

            print("Incorrect code! ")
            print("A new code will generate below: ")
            twofactor()
        else:
            flag = FALSE
            print ("Success !")
            login_success()
```

Comment: You wrote: `entercode = str(<something>)`, so `entercode ` is a string, and then you're comparing this: `if entercode != RandomCode:`, where `RandomCode` is a _list of integers_. Can a string ever be equal to a list? No, so `entercode != RandomCode` will always be `True`, and you'll enter infinite recursion.

Comment: Of course it must be a string. You also have to enter it *exactly* as it prints, brackets and commas and all, and test against that same string that you print.

Comment: Also, the recursive call to twofactor() is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
def login_success () :
    pass

def twofactor():

    global RandomCode
    RandomCode = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

    flag = True

    while flag:
        random.shuffle(RandomCode)
        # --- Here's what you needed --- 
        RandomCodeString = ''.join (str (num) for num in RandomCode[0:6])
        print(RandomCodeString)
        entercode = str(input("Enter the code: "))
        if entercode != RandomCodeString:

            print("Incorrect code! ")
            print("A new code will generate below: ")
            twofactor()
        else:
            flag = False
            print ("Success !")
            login_success()

twofactor ()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm still learning Python but I see what you meant. Can a string be compared to a list of integer (No duhh!) Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be simplified:

```
def twofactor():

    RandomCode = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

    while True:
        random.shuffle(RandomCode)
        Required = str(RandomCode[0:6])
        print(Required)
        entercode = input("Enter the code: ")
        if entercode != Required:
            print("Incorrect code! ")
            print("A new code will generate below: ")
        else:
            print ("Success !")
            login_success()
            return
```

Comment: Yes, agreed. Done.